# React Form with Express.js backend submits Null values into MySQL(XAMPP phpmyadmin) Columns

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, post

I am trying to submit data to a MySQL table, from a react form. my database is set up locally with XAMP. My backend end is powered by Express.js. I am able to submit data and get 200 response however all values are NULL.

HERE IS WHAT I HAVE ON MY BACKEND TO HANDLE POSTING DATA TO TABLE

```
//add partipant
app.post("/entries", (req, res) => {
  let data = {
    raceCategory: req.body.raceCategory,
    name: req.body.name,
    surname: req.body.surname,
    age: req.body.age,
    idNumber: req.body.idNumber,
    selectedGender: req.body.selectedGender,
    address: req.body.address,
    contactNo: req.body.contactNo,
    email: req.body.email,
    nationality: req.body.nationality,
    isClubMember: req.body.isClubMember,
    entryFee: req.body.entryFee,
    tShirtSize: req.body.tShirtSize,
    clubName: req.body.clubName,
    athleticProvince: req.body.athleticProvince,
    nextOfKin: req.body.nextOfKin,
    numberOfKin: req.body.numberOfKin,
  };

  let sql = "INSERT INTO participant SET ?";
  
  let query = dbConn.query(sql, data, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      res
        .status(500)
        .send(JSON.stringify({ status: 500, error: err, response: null }));
    } else {
      res
        .status(200)
        .send(JSON.stringify({ status: 200, error: null, response: results }));
    }
  });
});
```

ON MY FRONTEND I HAVE BELOW FUNCTION TO POST TO DATABASE

```
const postToDb = () => {
    console.log(formData);
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/entries", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ formData }),
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  };
```

When I console formData before post U get the expected object with values entered from the form. I am able to perform the post request as successfully. However all values are NULL in the database columns. Kindly advise if i am doing any wrong. Thanks in Advance!!